# list initialization compile error

Tags: c++, c++11

c++ 11 standard 8.5.4 example for list initializtion say:

```
std::map<std::string,int> anim = { {"bear",4}, {"cassowary",2}, {"tiger",7} };
```

But I have tried VC10, gcc 4.6 and Comeau, none of those compiler would let this pass ? Why is that ?

Comment: The C++11 standard is very new, not all compilers and libraries support everything yet.

Comment: GCC 4?5, 4.6 and 4.7 compile that if you specify `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: [Works](http://ideone.com/37oqu) for me on gcc 4.5.1 . What is the error, that you get? Perhaps you have not enabled `-std=c++0x`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think that is the correct answer to this question :)

Comment: You might want to compare the C++11 release date and the gcc 4.6.0 release date...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers in the comments.

I then checked back the c++ 98 and 03 standard and yea, 8.5.4 is definitely a new second in c++ 11 !
That's why it not being fully supported by all compilers.

After adding flag -std=c++0x with gcc 4.6.1 now this compiles fine.

Adding the testing code for anything who might need a reference:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    std::map<std::string,int> collection = {{"bear",4}, {"cassowary",2}, {"tiger",7}};
    for(auto it: collection)
        std::cout << it.first << " has value " << it.second << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```